# Difference between Кажется и Выглядит

Tags: словоупотребление, значения

I can't explain difference for english native speaker.

I am sure there are some differences, for example:

> Он выглядит более уверенным чем кажется.

или

> Мне кажется, мы потеряем деньги.

But I can't expain it.

Comment: `Он выглядит более уверенным чем кажется.` — example is grammatical yet unacceptable since makes no sense (or tending to unacceptability).

Comment: What's the problem, did you look it up in the dictionary?

Comment: @jwalker , "How does he look like?" — He looks like (for me, for his, for all) more [...] than it seems (to me, to his, to all). `Он выглядит более уверенным чем кажется ` the reader awaits further text `мне/им/ему/ей/всем`, otherwise it is unclear.

Comment: @Avtokod Sorry, my question was for the OP.

Comment: Можно сказать `он умнее чем кажется`, но (по-моему) нельзя `он выглядит более уверенным чем кажется` именно потому, что в данном контексте слова _выглядит_ и _кажется_ являются слишком близкими синонимами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Кажется` имеет возвратную частицу *-ся* `на себя`. Это грамматически сохранилось в польском языке, а в русском языке ушло в морфологическую форму:

```
  mi się wydaje      (Polish)
       \
        \
         \
мне кажет ся         (Russian)
```

Возвратная частица *-ся* обозначает "действия на себя, внутрь себя, между собой":

```
    Они целуются.           Действие между собой.
    Болт вворачивается.     Сам, магически-автоматически :)
    Ему кажется.            Видит свои мысленные образы. Бредит, галлюцинирует.
```

С другой стороны, я бы акцентировал, что приставка `вы-`, как правило, обозначает выдать наружу (вне, из себя).

```
     вы-дать          -- initial --
     вы-глядеть       выдать свой образ для всех
     вы-бросить       выдать быстро наружу
     вы-лить          выдать что-то жидкое, что льется
     вы-ставить       выдать, оставить там
```

Следовательно, один выдает, второй принимает.

```
    Он выглядит для всех как ..., но мне кажется, что ...
```

В конкретном примере из вопроса `Он выглядит более уверенным чем кажется.` логика требует разделить в пространстве (или во времени), кто передатчик, а кто приемник.

Comment: Строго говоря, `ся` - это суффикс.

Comment: Суффикс `-ся` означает возвратность, то есть направленность на себя, но по умолчанию, если не сказать _кажется мне_, но направлен на главного субъекта, о котором идет речь, то есть на _него_. Он _кажет себя_.

Comment: @farfareast , пока я не могу согласиться, не совсем понял, в чем возражение, нужно больше аргументов.

Comment: Я как раз то же самое хочу сказать: недостаточно аргументов в вашем логическом переходе: _Следовательно, один выдает, второй *принимает*_. Я могу согласиться с частью _один выдает_, (он вы-глядит, раз приставка вы-, то выдает, но почему _кажется_ - это обязательно _принимает_? Он выглядит для всех, и кажется для всех. Он тоже выдает: кажет (показывает) себя как будто...

Comment: _Казаться_ [(см. толковый словарь)](http://feb-web.ru/feb/ushakov/ush-abc/11/us1c8011.htm) имеет 3 значения: 1) выглядеть как (он кажется); 2) представляться воображению (мне кажется); 3) вводное слово (казалось). Что я хочу сказать в своем первом комментарии - это то, что если во фразе нет уточнения **мне** кажется, или **он** кажется, то по умолчанию подразумеваестя _он_: поскольку слово **он** уже фигурировало во фразе, и второй раз оно может быть опущено.  То есть подразумевается фраза: `Он выглядит более уверенным, чем он кажется.` а не: `Он выглядит более уверенным, чем мне кажется.`

Answer (score 1):

"Выглядит" could mean either "is like" or "looks like" depending on context. "Кажется" always means just "seem".

Answer (score 0):

If person says "Кажется", he doubts! "Кажется" has a bit of doubt.

Comment: And what is the difference in usage of *кажется* in two example sentences?

Answer (score 0):

`looks` and `seems` - isn't it?

He looks more confident then he seemed to be.
It seems, we'll lose the money.

I've changed the first sentence to "Он выглядит более уверенным, чем казалось" = "Он выглядит более уверенным, чем мы ожидали" = "He looks more confident then we expected".